# Javascript search bar only search title

Tags: javascript, search, hide

How can I search only on the b tag but not on the whole div.
Now i can search on the whole div, but I only want to be able to search on the title in the b tag. And if there is a name that is in the list, it has to be removed
HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="list">
        <div class="panel-header">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for users" id="searchName"/>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="user1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <b>Pieter</b><br>
                    (Laatste bericht)<br>
                    <i>12:01</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="user2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <b>Karel</b><br>
                    (Laatste bericht)<br>
                    <i>11:15</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="user3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <b>Pilot</b><br>
                    (Laatste bericht)<br>
                    <i>9:36</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
function contains(text_one, text_two){
    if (text_one.indexOf(text_two) != -1){
        return true;
    }
}

$("#searchName").keyup(function () {
    var searchName = $("#searchName").val().toLowerCase();
    $(".panel-body").each(function () {
        if(!contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchName)) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try: "if(!contains($(this).find('b').text().toLowerCase(), searchName)) {" ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm verdy new to javascript and need to look up a lot but could not find any real answers. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would it be ok if i'd add this as an answer and you'll approve it?

Comment: Sure, i'll do that for you

Comment: I'll have to wait 5 mins to approve it to :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find()` in the condition to focus on the element's child B tag:

Before:

```
if(!contains($(this).text().toLowerCase(), searchName)) {
```

After:

```
if(!contains($(this).find('b').text().toLowerCase(), searchName)) {
```